# Can `pip install foo-package==1.0.0` download different code today than it did yesterday

Tags: python, security, pypi

I need to make sure that the package which was allowed for a secure system will remain static if installed again in the future.  Can a bad actor (the package owner) trick user into downloading insecure/unvetted source code?

Comment: Have a look at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#hash-checking-mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PyPI maintainer here: Yes, it is possible, since `pip` will install whichever distribution is the optimal distribution. This commonly happens when a project uploads a source distribution (sdist) and then later uploads platform-specific wheels for a given release: `pip` will always prefer the wheel over the source distribution.

If you'd like to prevent this, you can specify the file hashes when installing via [hash-checking mode](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#hash-checking-mode).

Comment: How much secure is this?

Comment: Pip will never install a distribution whose hash does not match a provided hash.

Answer (score 0):

PyPI prohibits users from uploading a file with the same name.  So if the user uploads a package which has a wheel file that looks like `foo-1.0.0-py2py3-none-any.whl` they cannot update that file to contain other source code. However, what they can do is delete `v1.0.0` from PyPI change the source code and then upload both: `foo-1.0.0-py2-none-any.whl` and `foo-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl` effectively tricking the user into downloading a potentially malicious wheel.